# JavaScript function to convert string to numbers and add respective values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am stuck with this coding part to

Convert each alphabetic character entered in input field as follows – a=1, b=2 ,c=3, and so on to  z=26

Add the numeric values of each converted character together and display the result on the page

For example a = 1 b = 2 c =3 d = 4
So if I enter "add" in input field and click calculate it should display 9.

Comment: So where is the code you have a problem with? [Or try google... (link - "learning to code")](https://www.google.de/search?q=learning+to+code&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=iBurVMS2HMrDPJaGgfAC)

Comment: We can't help you if you don't explain what the problem is.

Comment: Wouldn't `'add'` be `9` (1+4+4)?

Comment: I tried working on many code format...did not get through it...i have up and deleted my code...but I had created variables from a to z and assigned values from 1 to 26..tried with alert function..it worked..but very limited functionality.

Comment: Sorry ..it is 9..typo..

Comment: I'd create an object with the letters as keys and their numbers as values.  That might be a simple way to get started.  Then you can look up each letter in the object.

Comment: What happens if I enter `¹←☐∎∂∃∇∏̸∏`?

Comment: Hmm, I smell a homework assignment.

Comment: If I type "add" in the input field and click on submit button it should display 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your letters into ASCII values.
See: [this](http://www.asciitable.com/)

and for example for "a", you could find his number like this:

```
var number = "a".charCodeAt(0) - 96;
```

97 is the ASCII number of "a", 98 of "b", etc... so minus 96 will give you the expected number.

**EDIT:**

Ok good point, if you have a serie of number, you just need to change them into string with `toSTring()` method and then you make a loop on this string with the `charCodeAt(i)` method as explained before. You even can verify the validity of each value of your string at each iteration to handle unexpected value.

Comment: This will produce `65439` for `"\uffff"` and `-64` for `" "`. Not sure if this is desired.